# path2D rotation badworking

Tags: javascript, matrix, canvas, path, 2d

I want to rotate objects using path2D but it doesn't rotate to size. While it works fine using ctx.rotate().

```js
const ctx = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas')).getContext('2d')
let rotation = 45
let p1 = new Path2D()

p1.rect(0, 0, 75, 75)

let p2 = new Path2D()

p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().translate(10, 10).scale(1, 1.2).
rotate(rotation / 180 * Math.PI)) // 45deg not rotate

ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
ctx.fill(p2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DOMMatrix` interface takes rotation as degrees, not as radians. Yes, that's a shame that it's one of the only JS interfaces that does so, yes it's painful, everyday, but it's too late to make a change<sup>1</sup>.
For the history note, I believe it's because `DOMMatrix` is actually "a better `SVGMatrix`", and that `SVGMatrix` had it in degrees, because SVG has rotations only in degrees. `DOMMatrix` didn't have to deal only with degrees though, CSS can set angle units, and JS math operations are done in radians.

Anyway, that actually makes your code a bit simpler, though when you'll wan to roll back to a context transform you'll have to remember this discrepancy.

```js
const ctx = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas')).getContext('2d')
let rotation = 45
let p1 = new Path2D()

p1.rect(0, 0, 75, 75)

let p2 = new Path2D()

p2.addPath(p1, new DOMMatrix().translate(10, 10).scale(1, 1.2).
rotate(rotation)) // in stoopid deg

ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
ctx.fill(p2)
```

<sub>1. Though if I get angry enough one of these days I may propose `rotateRadians()` et al. methods to be added...</sub>